# Revert to unsumbitted changelists

Tags: perforce

If you have three or more pending changelists (not yet submitted) and in all of them you introduce changes to a particular file, can you discard the changes done in the last (third) changelist with out losing the changes made to that file into the two others/previous changelists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the pending changelists are in different workspaces, then what you do in one doesn't (and can't) affect any of the others, unless you submit it.

If all of the pending changelists are in the same workspace, the situation is impossible in the first place; multiple pending changelists within a workspace can't all contain the same file with different changes, because only one copy of that file exists in the workspace.

Comment: My attempt was to determine if perforce has a feature similar to git's unstaged & staged mechanism. Turns out that you can have multiple copies/versions of a file(not yet submitted) into multiple shelved pending changelists.

Comment: Yup, shelves are a different thing altogether!  Those exist on the server completely independently of one another, so you can discard one without affecting the others.  The flipside is that there isn't a concept of "stacked" shelves -- if one shelf builds off another, this isn't reflected in the metadata in any way, so you can't readily do subtractive operations on them the way you can with submitted revisions in the depot.